# how to extract value from a tag using Beautifulsoup in python?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

i have the below tag :

```
</div><input autocomplete="off" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" name="javax.faces.ViewState" type="hidden" value="qhaB3+BPc7RCn9OJu7uc3ljgv5tl0
virgu+E+kY0cpPjkXntWS6mR27AlJl9lRssNJtCiibknNxLXHzipBdzSrg0Bc9jmqJZGR/UpQMr4QvE0Y1eESruoQ/JZ1IZWkW3KL3px7sG509UnLCC52y/bzhYOjwY+mCh/o0LVa9Tn7c0PC/
UTwA56UUX5rEU9ENZhT2MiU7fXCFTq8gUw5mEl3Cd8E5DPGTDHk2wdGalVOwfRlnUDnFJ8h8zzq4N02D70YK7+Tewz+rBGEUrnq3/9pLiul/MoSgcahnV4164gUOyX0ywpmYYN0j3xEfHd9Odc
TsQ7YWRsRBz/kdxd8njKyu80QFMpH3viJmonzCxVR53FCDF2XL5eoYhtXZ7A0p04A3gOSPEV4RBHDCbK2JhyBpoDTSs6y8MweKSfw2C3Sza1nF01Bdi+UPyulhZsoFpwIoWIdag3ATCGwz8Vs2
IAK3IywqEKYvrFmMffNiFfg4+Otqv6VqOvPEnwJivosx9OJ/FhsbN9LGwN7vVGFlTnW/oYMEQsufEjUKK9ve+ne88k9N0hy0VYiLKy7IIvys+QdKxYW/XM/G54R0NJhCDlOKwt/j1HElvP79O2
Lh33dQqBkFVE62bEWiXd8zitYB/zsOpjB6JbK46LAvuYtuTpnqrCio1shmqmq6eGgnMksoMUAciNJY9Qa4BciR5qMkq3o1nb3OC6BR11aoNeRsGwJeAPCCT5GTzpPi4WWPX0IYTqCiLpxov67c
vI2TQCaxTCMLTuwzZHnEg5QR5q/57r2FHtb2ruYfk43IT23ylVpcI9qDIZJx/pVgZfRzUT+acJtMd/j7TEC5ur+AYdshs7SdhxDg2F4JNPV/3BL4QdzrGRyS1hQYVajyRdIp1J9Iih8QNt7moc
cXRK1FEF2iyLBXLKQqdhEq79p2jWg7eZRtIkPXjYloGKxmfas5j/1GuLrlh0F8tjB3Ixhnu2dZrAUfV0ARMzI4Dr+TB7C+hdw+1ehytM6a0HpvipTVCPOLxcx36RMypNLPfZZJDQm2imwGr1Jr
4uZOkiS7cna2pG5gg8HhOAvu1q77LQCFAIwwXX5gN/EJ+l7E3Xh4BBrQdg11HCbjZ5G6MYwAUGosjl5TnQvVDSGrqEeBUThY4hO4c"/>
```

i want to extract the value from that, i tried to use find but cannot get it.
Can anyone help ?

Comment: Where is the code that you tried with? and what is the expected output?

Comment: i want to extract view-state value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the attribute `value=...` you can use `element['value']` or `element.get('value')`.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<input autocomplete="off" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" name="javax.faces.ViewState" type="hidden" value="qhaB3+BPc7RCn9OJu7uc3ljgv5tl0
virgu+E+kY0cpPjkXntWS6mR27AlJl9lRssNJtCiibknNxLXHzipBdzSrg0Bc9jmqJZGR/UpQMr4QvE0Y1eESruoQ/JZ1IZWkW3KL3px7sG509UnLCC52y/bzhYOjwY+mCh/o0LVa9Tn7c0PC/
UTwA56UUX5rEU9ENZhT2MiU7fXCFTq8gUw5mEl3Cd8E5DPGTDHk2wdGalVOwfRlnUDnFJ8h8zzq4N02D70YK7+Tewz+rBGEUrnq3/9pLiul/MoSgcahnV4164gUOyX0ywpmYYN0j3xEfHd9Odc
TsQ7YWRsRBz/kdxd8njKyu80QFMpH3viJmonzCxVR53FCDF2XL5eoYhtXZ7A0p04A3gOSPEV4RBHDCbK2JhyBpoDTSs6y8MweKSfw2C3Sza1nF01Bdi+UPyulhZsoFpwIoWIdag3ATCGwz8Vs2
IAK3IywqEKYvrFmMffNiFfg4+Otqv6VqOvPEnwJivosx9OJ/FhsbN9LGwN7vVGFlTnW/oYMEQsufEjUKK9ve+ne88k9N0hy0VYiLKy7IIvys+QdKxYW/XM/G54R0NJhCDlOKwt/j1HElvP79O2
Lh33dQqBkFVE62bEWiXd8zitYB/zsOpjB6JbK46LAvuYtuTpnqrCio1shmqmq6eGgnMksoMUAciNJY9Qa4BciR5qMkq3o1nb3OC6BR11aoNeRsGwJeAPCCT5GTzpPi4WWPX0IYTqCiLpxov67c
vI2TQCaxTCMLTuwzZHnEg5QR5q/57r2FHtb2ruYfk43IT23ylVpcI9qDIZJx/pVgZfRzUT+acJtMd/j7TEC5ur+AYdshs7SdhxDg2F4JNPV/3BL4QdzrGRyS1hQYVajyRdIp1J9Iih8QNt7moc
cXRK1FEF2iyLBXLKQqdhEq79p2jWg7eZRtIkPXjYloGKxmfas5j/1GuLrlh0F8tjB3Ixhnu2dZrAUfV0ARMzI4Dr+TB7C+hdw+1ehytM6a0HpvipTVCPOLxcx36RMypNLPfZZJDQm2imwGr1Jr
4uZOkiS7cna2pG5gg8HhOAvu1q77LQCFAIwwXX5gN/EJ+l7E3Xh4BBrQdg11HCbjZ5G6MYwAUGosjl5TnQvVDSGrqEeBUThY4hO4c"/>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select_one('input[id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"]')['value'])
```

Prints:

```
qhaB3+BPc7RCn9OJu7uc3ljgv5tl0
virgu+E+kY0cpPjkXntWS6mR27AlJl9lRssNJtCiibknNxLXHzipBdzSrg0Bc9jmqJZGR/UpQMr4QvE0Y1eESruoQ/JZ1IZWkW3KL3px7sG509UnLCC52y/bzhYOjwY+mCh/o0LVa9Tn7c0PC/
UTwA56UUX5rEU9ENZhT2MiU7fXCFTq8gUw5mEl3Cd8E5DPGTDHk2wdGalVOwfRlnUDnFJ8h8zzq4N02D70YK7+Tewz+rBGEUrnq3/9pLiul/MoSgcahnV4164gUOyX0ywpmYYN0j3xEfHd9Odc
TsQ7YWRsRBz/kdxd8njKyu80QFMpH3viJmonzCxVR53FCDF2XL5eoYhtXZ7A0p04A3gOSPEV4RBHDCbK2JhyBpoDTSs6y8MweKSfw2C3Sza1nF01Bdi+UPyulhZsoFpwIoWIdag3ATCGwz8Vs2
IAK3IywqEKYvrFmMffNiFfg4+Otqv6VqOvPEnwJivosx9OJ/FhsbN9LGwN7vVGFlTnW/oYMEQsufEjUKK9ve+ne88k9N0hy0VYiLKy7IIvys+QdKxYW/XM/G54R0NJhCDlOKwt/j1HElvP79O2
Lh33dQqBkFVE62bEWiXd8zitYB/zsOpjB6JbK46LAvuYtuTpnqrCio1shmqmq6eGgnMksoMUAciNJY9Qa4BciR5qMkq3o1nb3OC6BR11aoNeRsGwJeAPCCT5GTzpPi4WWPX0IYTqCiLpxov67c
vI2TQCaxTCMLTuwzZHnEg5QR5q/57r2FHtb2ruYfk43IT23ylVpcI9qDIZJx/pVgZfRzUT+acJtMd/j7TEC5ur+AYdshs7SdhxDg2F4JNPV/3BL4QdzrGRyS1hQYVajyRdIp1J9Iih8QNt7moc
cXRK1FEF2iyLBXLKQqdhEq79p2jWg7eZRtIkPXjYloGKxmfas5j/1GuLrlh0F8tjB3Ixhnu2dZrAUfV0ARMzI4Dr+TB7C+hdw+1ehytM6a0HpvipTVCPOLxcx36RMypNLPfZZJDQm2imwGr1Jr
4uZOkiS7cna2pG5gg8HhOAvu1q77LQCFAIwwXX5gN/EJ+l7E3Xh4BBrQdg11HCbjZ5G6MYwAUGosjl5TnQvVDSGrqEeBUThY4hO4c
```

Or:

```
print(soup.find('input', id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0").get('value'))
```